# Add class to given element does not work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use vanilla js in my project. I have some functions, and I have problem with one of them. The idea of script is: click  link on main page, which redirects to other page; add class to #div1. When I click a link and I'm redirecting to other page - nothing hepens. I can't find I do wrong.

HTML from main page:

```
<a href="pagelink" id="view">text</a>
```

HTML from other page:

```
<div class="row" id="div1"></div>
<div class="row" id="div2"></div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    var hideDivOne = document.getElementById("div1"),
        View = document.getElementById("view");

    function swap() {
        hideDivOne.className += " notdisplayed";
    }

    if(View){
        View.addEventListener("click", swap, false);
    }
}
```

CSS

`.notdisplayed {display:none;}`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/196038/1838811

Comment: Where is your JS? Is it linked to your main page or to the other page?

Comment: @Badacadabra JS is linked to main page and the other page

Comment: @Olchus So what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to hide "#view" on the other page?

Comment: @Badacadabra After click on #view on main page I want to be redirected to other page where #div1 will be hidden.

Comment: It's very easy to do... What's blocking you? "#view" is an HTML link, so when you click it, there is an automatic redirection. Then, on the other page, you just need to hide the div. Do you want a demo?

Comment: @Badacadabra yes, please! To be honest I have spend some time, and I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
hideDivOne.className += " notdisplayed";
```

try with:

```
hideDivOne.classList.add("notdisplayed");
```

and if you want to remove this class:

```
hideDivOne.classList.remove("notdisplayed");
```

or toggle class:

```
hideDivOne.classList.toggle("notdisplayed");
```

Comment: the problem is that the function does not work. I'm not sure but maybe that's happening because of reload? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make sense... On the other page, `View` is `null` because your link is not in the HTML anymore! Therefore, nothing is executed, which is not what you want.

In fact, you do not need JS in your main page. Just use the native behavior of the HTML link by putting the right URL in the `href` attribute: `<a href="other_page.html" id="view">text</a>`

When you are on the other page, you can hide the div using the `style` property. Look at this demo:

```css
.row {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="div1"></div>
<div class="row" id="div2"></div>
```

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("div1").style.display = 'none';
};
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#div1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="div1"></div>
<div class="row" id="div2"></div>
```

Comment: but... How "<a href="pagelink" id="view">text</a>" is not HTML?
I don't need to hide div after typical page reload. I want to hide it when hyperlink on main page is clicked and I'm redirected to the other page.